# XBoard protocol documentation wanted (chess)

Tags: documentation, chess

I am looking for XBoard documentation. XBoard is a communication protocol between chess engines and chess GUIs.

I know about http://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html , but seem to miss what a engine has to send/receive for communication with a board.

Anything better then the advice to reverse engineer the protocol either from a GUI Implementation (e.g.: xchess or eboard) or a chess engine would be great. Even a commented snippet from a board/engine communication might help.

Comment: This is a question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your link tells us that H.G.Muller is the current maintainer of the interface. [His page](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/interfacing.txt) shows the  minimal interface you need to implement.

Comment: ok, I missed that. If you put it in an answer, I will accept it and work with that document. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*From the comments:*

Your link tells us that [H.G.Muller](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Harm+Geert+Muller) is the current maintainer of the interface. [His page](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/interfacing.txt) shows the minimal interface you need to implement.

Comment: First thing that came up on google with a direct link to the minimal and exact protocol descriptions I was looking for. +1 to both you and the question asker.